# Get field value of parameter field in Crystal Reports

Tags: php, object, com, crystal-reports, report

I'm building an application in PHP that accesses Crystal Reports via COM object. My problem is that after I create a parameter field in the report that I'm opening in PHP, I don't know how to get the "Value Field". This is where you set the Database field that you connect the parameter field with.
I can get the current value of that field or it's name with something like: $field->CurrentValue(); $field->Name(); but I can't find anywhere an option for getting the "Value Field".

[image]

Comment: Do you want to get the SQL table column name with which the parameter is associated?

Comment: @Robert Niestroj Yes that's exactly what I want to get but I think the table name will be necessary also. Any advice where to start will be greatly appreciated.